# how to detect two hot key in win form app like CTRL +C , CTRL+ W

Tags: c#, winforms

my question is how to detect two hot keys in win form application 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>CTRL</kbd>,<kbd>K</kbd> like visual studio commenting command

**I need to simulate VS hot key For commenting a line of code**

Comment: He's asking how to detect the sequence - Ctrl+C, followed by Ctrl+K - not one independent from the other.

Comment: @MattDavis that is exactly what i want

Comment: @mohammedsameeh: if you want to handle two hot keys sequentially you need to check for `sequence` , check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private bool _isFirstKeyPressedW = false;

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control & e.KeyCode == Keys.W) 
    {
        _isFirstKeyPressedW = true;
    }
    if (_isFirstKeyPressedW) 
    {
        if (e.Control & e.KeyCode == Keys.S) 
        {
            //write your code 
        } 
        else 
        {
            _isFirstKeyPressedW = e.KeyCode == Keys.W;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
   {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple way is... There is a Windows API Function called ProcessCmdKey, by overriding this function we can achieve what we want**

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
   if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C)) {
      MessageBox.Show("You have pressed the shortcut Ctrl+C");
      return true;
   }
   return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Microsoft Documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx)

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400325/3082414)

Comment: Please give attribution when you pull an answer from another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596600/cant-detect-a-ctrl-key-shortcut-on-keydown-events-whenever-theres-a-readonly/4596641#4596641).

Comment: Actually i gave the link to the original post. your like is a 2nd dupe

Answer (score 0):

if you want to handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>K</kbd> you need to maintain a state variable.

Set the Form `KeyPreview` property to `true` and handle the Form `KeyDown` event.

Try This:

```
   this.KeyPreview=true;
   private bool isFirstKeyPressed= false;
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {               
            isFirstKeyPressed = true;                
        }


        if (isFirstKeyPressed)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.K)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ctrl+C and Ctrl+K pressed Sequentially");
                /*write your code here*/
                isFirstKeyPressed= false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `isFirstKeyPressed` ought to be reset to false in *every* case after it is set to true, right?

Comment: yes it has to be but  if user press `Ctrl+C` , `Ctrl` and before pressing the `K` itself  `isFirstKeyPressed` becomes false.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi your code is right but it miss an important thing if you press (CTRL+C) then followed by any random character and then (CTRL+W) will be executed i will post the code , thanks